# Fibonacci sequence matrix

Tags: matrices, fibonacci-numbers

Let us recall that the famous Fibonacci sequence: $0,1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,\dots$
is defined as follows:

we put $\phi_0 = 0, \phi_1 = 1$ and define
$\phi_{n+2} = \phi_{n+1} + \phi_n$. 
We want to find a formula for $\phi_n$. To do this

a) Take a 2×2 matrix $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}$ such that

$\begin{pmatrix}\phi_{n+2}\\ \phi_{n+1}\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix}\phi_{n+1}\\ \phi_n\end{pmatrix}$

b) Diagonalize $A$ and find a formula for $A^n$.

c) Find a formula for $\phi_n$. (You will need to compute an inverse and perform
multiplication here).

`d) Show that the vector $(\phi_{n+1} /\phi_n , 1)^T$ converges to an eigenvector of $A$.

What do you think, is it a coincidence?

***for part b) I diagonalized in a way that was not very clean. How do you do c) and d)?

Comment: Sorry I dont know how to make matrix notation but if someone could tell me how I can fix how this problem looks! Since it clearly doesnt make sense now

Comment: You seem to be using a lot of unicode characters, potentially copy-pasting from a PDF. Please consider using the formatting guidelines for math-content posts and format your posts with LaTeX. http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex (or use @probablyme 's link, which is more verbose and helpful)

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). If you copied from somewhere, it didn't come out right.

Comment: Matrices [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/5023/290196).

Comment: Do you want it to read $\begin{pmatrix}\phi_{n+2}\\ \phi_{n+1}\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}\phi_{n+1}\\ \phi_n\end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: yes! just like that.

Comment: @readyforthebettys I have tidied it up a bit, but I had to shorten c) because I could not understand what you meant. If you look at the edited version, you should be able to make further changes yourself.